# Polymer, change route on chained app-route element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using the app-route element from https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route on a project with the following structure:

A `my-app` element containing the following code:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:page"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>

<iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  <store-main-page 
    name="loja" 
    route="{{subroute}}" 
    categories="[[categories]]">
  </store-main-page>
  ...
</iron-pages>
...
```

A `store-main-page` element with:

```
<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:page"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>

<iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  <category-page 
    name="categoria" 
    route="{{subroute}}" 
    selected-category="{{selectedCategory}}"
    cart="{{cart}}">
  </category-page>
  ...
</iron-pages>
...
```

So, accessing `/` path a welcome page will be displayed and accessing `/loja/categoria`, the `my-app` will call `store-main-page` that will call the `category-page`.

My problem is, I want to authenticate the user before display the `store-main-page`, and if the user is not authenticated, redirect him to welcome page on `/`. Is there a way to do this using `app-route`?

The only way I found to change page using `app-route` is to call

```
this.set('route.path', 'path');
```

But this does not work on chained routes, on my situation, this will result on redirecting to `/loja/` path, which is not what I want.

How can I change the route on a parent element? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out that `app-location` is just an interface between `iron-location` and `app-route`.

So I solved the problem adding an `iron-location` to my child element, and changing its `path` property.

The exact code was:

```
  <iron-location id="ironLocation"></iron-location>
...
</template>

<script>
...
  attached: function() {                    
    if (!userAuth()) {            
      this.$.ironLocation.set('path', '/');            
    } else {
      ...
    }                                      
  }
...
```

I don't know if this is the ideal solution, but it works.